# Prevent content from overlapping the button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap.

I am trying to show View button in the same line as my content (div with class pull-left). I want that the content should be shown in the same line and if it overflows it should show with `...` using `text-overflow: ellipsis`

To show the button I have had to use `position: absolute;`

This makes the content overlap the button. I want the output similar to this: https://gyazo.com/5f37b6ffe33163be0dbee22272eea0f0

such that it should work in all screen sizes. So it should add `...` automatically without lapping the button in all screen sizes.

This is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k9owzuw9/

**Please note:** I need to use table itself and both the content and button in the same column (td).

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to get desired output.

```css
.shorten {
      width: 400px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body, html {
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.full-width{
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.overlay-button{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="pull-left full-width shorten">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in justo vehicula, efficitur tortor quis, condimentum massa. Aliquam ut luctus arcu, iaculis lacinia ex. Aliquam sodales auctor augue sit amet iaculis. Praesent lacinia nunc id tortor suscipit, ut vulputate lacus ultrices. Quisque volutpat ultrices ultrices. In mollis et dolor a pellentesque. Nam ac cursus dui. Nulla facilisi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur faucibus pretium tellus, quis suscipit purus varius nec. Proin ut tellus tortor. 
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right overlay-button">
          <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
            View
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
        </div>        
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't work. If I resize the browser this is how it looks: https://gyazo.com/eebe869830b00d1f2f5fe85828bf6167 also you have simply specified 400px width which I obviously can't use it because on a large screen it would occupy just 400px. One solution is to use 100% width - View button width using calc function but sadly that is not supported on all browsers.

Comment: @TimLiberty, this is just an example code snippet. It's up to her/him how he change the attributes.

Comment: In that case the answer doesn't fit the question at all. Question clearly says: **such that it should work in all screen sizes. So it should add ... automatically without lapping the button in all screen sizes.**